# using twig path function in handlerbars.js

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars as my javascript template engine. I am using a simple form as template and call it again and again in my twig file of symfony2 framework.

I am using following twig block to escape the curly brackets conflict of handlebars and twig template:

```
 {% verbatim %}
```

But when I use the path() function to route my form it also gets ignored in this block. I am also using few variable above the form so can't use the twig ignoring block below form action.

thanks in advance.

Comment: show us some code with this problem

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle)

see how to use it here: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing the delimiter used in handlebars. Not sure exactly how you do it, but I've had to do this in a similar scenario only using Ractive:

delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],

tripleDelimiters: [ '[[[', ']]]' ],